# R ggplot2 & gganimate: animation changes at end

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to create this figure that animates over time using the gganimate library, going from the 'baseline' timepoint to the 'late' timepoint'. However for some reason, the image changes between frames 22-24 and again between 42-44. It throws off the visualization. But I am not sure how to fix it. Many thanks!

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tweenr)
library(gganimate)
library(treemapify)

set.seed(1)

colors <- c("turquoise", "gold", "yellowgreen", "dodgerblue", "firebrick", "orchid4",
            "grey74", "forestgreen", "deeppink2", "grey0", "slateblue", "sienna2", 
            "khaki2", "steelblue", "darksalmon", "darksalmon")

tweened <- tween_states(list(PID50baseline, PID50late, PID50baseline), 
                        tweenlength = 8, statelength = 8, 
                        ease = 'cubic-in-out', nframes = 50)

animated_plot <- ggplot(tweened, 
                        aes(area = Number, fill = Cluster.Name,
                            subgroup=Type, frame = .frame)) + 
  geom_treemap(fixed = T) + 
  geom_treemap_subgroup_border(fixed = T) + 
  geom_treemap_subgroup_text(place = "centre", grow = T, alpha = 0.5,
                             colour = "black", fontface = "italic", 
                             min.size = 0,fixed = T) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

animation::ani.options(interval = 1/10)

gganimate(animated_plot, "animated_treemap_PID50.gif", title_frame = T,
          ani.width = 200, ani.height = 200)
```

The data I used for this:

```
dput(PID50baseline)
structure(list(Cluster.Name = structure(c(13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 15L), .Label = c("Cluster 
13", "Cluster 14", "Cluster 17", "Cluster 18", "Cluster 19", "Cluster 20", 
"Cluster 27", "Cluster 35", "Cluster 36", "Cluster 40", "Cluster 41", 
"Cluster 42", "Cluster 5", "Cluster 6", "Non-clonal"), class = "factor"), 
Number = c(5L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 28L), Type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Defective", 
"Intact"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Cluster.Name", 
"Number", "Type"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))

dput(PID50late)
structure(list(Cluster.Name = structure(c(13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 15L), .Label = c("Cluster 13", 
"Cluster 14", "Cluster 17", "Cluster 18", "Cluster 19", "Cluster 20", 
"Cluster 27", "Cluster 35", "Cluster 36", "Cluster 40", "Cluster 41", 
"Cluster 42", "Cluster 5", "Cluster 6", "Non-clonal"), class = "factor"), 
Number = c(2L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 18L, 59L), Type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Defective", 
"Intact"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Cluster.Name", 
"Number", "Type"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `treemapify` [omits areas with a size of 0](https://github.com/wilkox/treemapify/blob/58e6650266641710865514502698ac24d1ce4c40/R/treemapify.R#L159). This could be the reason for your problem. In other words, replacing 0 with a small positive value greater than 0 (and using 16 distinct colors) gives you something like this:

```
tweened$Number[tweened$Number==0] <- 1e-10
colors <- unname(randomcoloR::distinctColorPalette(nlevels(tweened$Cluster.Name)))
```

[image]